# Canceling a test subscription is not working as intended in Android

Tags: android, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I am aware of Google's recent update on test subscriptions renew more quickly than normal to aid in testing. Eg: 1 month - 5 minutes. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/01/faster-renewals-for-test-subscriptions.html

I purchased a subscription, within a minute I cancel it and I waited for 5 to 10 min and then I queried subscriptions `mBillingClient.queryPurchases("subs")` but I can still see the canceled item in the result with the purchaseState 0(Purchased). I tried multiple times with more than 10-15 min gap before queryPurchases but no luck.

I am not sure why the canceled item shows in purchases even after a long wait.

Later I noticed if I clear Playstore Data and Cache everything worked temporarily. After 1 hour if I try to purchase the same product it shows `Error retrieving information from server[RPC:S-7:AEC-500 NWDB-WFVV-ZPAXE]`

Is this how we have to test cancel subscriptions?
What that error if i purchase the subscription again?

[image]